# Running a diffent code for each block of file

Tags: python

I have an output file from some numeric calculation. The output file looks like

> aa ab ac ad ae   ┐
>   ba bb bc bd be   ┘  Block of 5 strings
>   0.5 1.2 0.3 aaa bbb  ┐
>   0.2 8.2 3.3 ccc ddd  ┃ Block of 3 float + 2 string
>   0.5 1.3 0.6 eee ggg  ┘
>   0.11  0.444  0.333 0.777 0.88  ┐
>   0.41  0.544  0.313 0.797 0.01 ┃
>   0.11  0.447  0.333 0.777 0.88 ┃  Block of 6 float
>   0.17  0.444  0.333 0.787 0.03 ┃
>   0.11  0.444  0.333 0.777 0.88 ┘

which means, it forms block of some patterns. What I want to do is to read this file, and do some stuff for each block seperately.

For the simplest approach, I wrote the code like

```
file = open("myfile", "r")
for i, line in enumerate(file):
    if i <= 1:
        # do some stuff 1.
    elif 1< i <=4 :
        # do some stuff 2
    elif 4 < i :
        # do some stuff 3
file.close()
```

and specify the line number manually whenever I run the program. The problem is that the line number of output file varies from file to file (but the pattern is same), and before I check it manually by eye, I don't know how long each block will be. What is the efficient approach handling this problem?

The size of each file is about 100~1000MB, and each contains about 500000~ 5000000 lines.

Comment: Say your patterns are based only on float and string. Starting from first line, keep a count of both of them and do it until the next line also has the same counts, else move on to the next block of your code. Does that help?

Comment: Do the three types of blocks *always* come as 2, 3 and 6 lines respectively or is this just an example?

Comment: @timgeb The line varies. Some file has 2,3,6 lines while others has 2,5,16 lines, etc.

Comment: ah but you cant have a block of type 1 after a block of type 3, right?

Comment: @timgeb Yes. The order of blocks is always the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regular expressions to check which pattern each line matches and then execute the respective code block for each line.

```
import re

for x in lines:
    ## matches any number of floats
    if re.match("^([0-9\.]+\s?)+$", x):
        print "do stuff 3"

    ## matches 3 floats and 2 strings
    elif re.match("^([0-9\.]+\s?){3}(\w+\s?){2}$", x):
        print "do stuff 2"

    ## matches 5 strings
    elif re.match("^(\w+\s?){5}$", x):
        print "do stuff 1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach:

```
a = '''aa ab ac ad ae
ba bb bc bd be
0.5 1.2 0.3 aaa bbb
0.2 8.2 3.3 ccc ddd
0.5 1.3 0.6 eee ggg
0.11 0.444 0.333 0.777 0.88
0.41 0.544 0.313 0.797 0.01
0.11 0.447 0.333 0.777 0.88
0.17 0.444 0.333 0.787 0.03
0.11 0.444 0.333 0.777 0.88'''

for line in a.split('\n'):
    if line[0].isalpha():
        print 'Group1'
    elif line[0].isdigit() and line[-1].isalpha():
        print 'Group2'
    elif line[0].isdigit() and line[-1].isdigit():
        print 'Group3'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
f = open("demo.txt","r")
data = f.readlines()
start = "┐"
end = "┘"
demo_temp_list =[]
final_list = []
for d in data:
    if start in d:
        demo_temp_list = []
        demo_temp_list.append(d)
    elif end in d:
        demo_temp_list.append(d)
        final_list.append(demo_temp_list)
    else:
        demo_temp_list.append(d)

for index,final_data in enumerate(final_list):
    print "Group ", index+1
    print final_data
    print "----------"
```

output:

```
Group  1
['aa ab ac ad ae \xe2\x94\x90\n', 'ba bb bc bd be \xe2\x94\x98 Block of 5 strings\n']
----------
Group  2
['0.5 1.2 0.3 aaa bbb \xe2\x94\x90\n', '0.2 8.2 3.3 ccc ddd \xe2\x94\x83 Block of 3 float + 2 string\n', '0.5 1.3 0.6 eee ggg \xe2\x94\x98\n']
----------
Group  3
['0.11 0.444 0.333 0.777 0.88 \xe2\x94\x90\n', '0.41 0.544 0.313 0.797 0.01 \xe2\x94\x83\n', '0.11 0.447 0.333 0.777 0.88 \xe2\x94\x83 Block of 6 float\n', '0.17 0.444 0.333 0.787 0.03 \xe2\x94\x83\n', '0.11 0.444 0.333 0.777 0.88 \xe2\x94\x98']
----------
```